# z-index on absolute div

Tags: html, css

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3hdjxxf/)

I have two divs, A & B:

```
<div class="a">
    A
</div>
<div class="b">
    b
</div>
```

I want div B to be behind div A. I do not wish to change the order of the markup.

I have tried z-index, with no luck.

```
.a{
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 99;
}
.b{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements. `.a{ position:relative; …}`

Comment: Ok, how would i get my absolute div positioned behind it then? A relative wrapper?

Comment: Here's a fiddle what @CBroe said to demonstrate it to you: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/ta62Lmd0/

Comment: You just position `.a`, as I have already shown.

Answer (score 1):

Giving `position: relative` to 'a' will fix your problem. **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h3hdjxxf/2/)**

z-index will work with `position:relative` only.

```
.a{
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  z-index: 10;
  position:relative;
}

.b{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the z-index to -1 for class b

```
.b{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```